# Describing and rewriting example code from an exam paper

Tags: c, syntax

Here are a few example of bad programming. The aim is to know what the code is doing and rewrite it in better code.

[image: q]
<sub>(source: [gyazo.com](http://gyazo.com/4cb5f604f9d57561245544187b0a2139.png?1366209953))</sub>

[image: q]
<sub>(source: [gyazo.com](http://gyazo.com/c3739424a78ccc3b4b90f7ccaf1317a7.png?1366209918))</sub>

What I try to do is type it in as it is, compile it and try to figure out what's doing. But I make very little progress.
This is an exam paper question, so I can't afford to send ages trying to figure this out but at the same time it's a full question.

What are these code doing and how I can I figure them out (faster)?

Thank you.

EDIT:
I'm not asking for code. I'm asking for explanations to code. So I can't really give snippet.

Comment: I see no code snippets - but two tiny unhappy smileys...

Comment: "What are these code doing?" - no, do your own exam.  "how I can I figure them out (faster)?" - closing as not constructive, there are too many possible answers to this.

Comment: It's not about having code. It's about knowing what the code it dding.

Comment: That first example is one of the all-time-classics written by the masters! Not 'bad programming'. But perhaps not very readable.

Comment: Don't use computer. Just supply some inputs based on the argument types and hand-trace the code. These are pretty trivial.

Comment: @djechlin "Do your own exam" I'm asking it to be do for me. I'm just trying learn.

Comment: @thomthom :P Same here. Right click and see image in new tab

Comment: I spoke too soon. People closing the question: read the whole thing, it's not just a "do my exam for me" type question

Comment: @Earlz But I write any code if I don'r understand what these are doing. That's where I'm stuck.

Comment: There is no magic trick to understanding the code, you just need to have a solid understanding of C. If you are having trouble, you should talk to your instructor about it. Obviously, they expect that they have taught you enough to be able to figure it out, otherwise they wouldn't be testing you on it. If this is not the case, then it needs to be brought to their attention. Either they are not doing as good of a job as they thought, or else they can help you get the extra resources you need in order to catch up.

Comment: @AdegokeA See my comment about the section B code below in comments to code.atodi answer. Maybe it will help you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is to practice more (and learn new concepts). The more you practice, greater the variety of code you are exposed to. Such things might appear as very complicated to beginners [in the 1st C code i saw, I was wondering why is `*` multiplication placed before variable name `int * a` ;) ]

There are many good refrences you can use to clear your confusions like [this](http://boredzo.org/pointers/)  or [this](http://pw1.netcom.com/~tjensen/ptr/pointers.htm)

Answer (score 1):

These are very basic and brilliant codes.
Just do a dry run of codes on a paper and you'll easily get the answer about what they are doing.
like, in B, we are creating an array of same values `item` until `b != -1`.
similarly, just assume some values and solve it on a paper and re write with proper lines and indentation.

Comment: Thank you. I just have a hard time understanding how the pointers work. Like *(a++), what does that do?

Comment: So is *(a++)  the same as a++?

Comment: No, it's not, but `x=*(a++)` is the same as `a++; x=*a`. `a` is a variable holding an address. The address stored in that variable is first incremented with the `a++`. The resulting address is then dererenced, which simply means the value at that address in memory is loaded. To understand pointers, you just need to understand that memory is a sequence of bytes each with their own address, and variables are simply convenient labels to refer to the data currently stored at a particular memory address.

Comment: to understand pointers better, [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_pointers.htm)
and yes, @sh1ftst0rm is correct.

Comment: Actually, there is **no assignment** in the code of section B. What it does is checking how many times the initial array *a* contains the value *item*. I.e. it iterates the array *a* recursively and if it finds that `a[b] == item` it adds *1*. E.g. if array *a* contains *items* in three of its elements/slots the function must return 3. The part `return (a[b] == item)` returns ether 1 (if element equals item) or 0 (if it not equals). In C, the result of the Boolean operation can be evaluated to integer

Comment: @code.atodi: Your description of what section B does is incorrect; @informatik01 is correct. I made the same mistake at first, but it is an equality test, not an assignment. Also, your comment "`*(a++)` is the address of a variable whose value is a+1" is ambiguous: the value of the *address* is "a+1" (assuming the original value of a), the value of the *variable* at that address is unspecified.

Comment: @sh1ftst0rm Yup, he probably was in hurry.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have understood what the code is doing just change variable and function names. Done.
In this case "Bad programming" is using poor names for variables, which doesn't explicit the purpose of the variable itself

Edit: 
the second task of your assignment is `rewrite it in better code.`.That's the beauty of the exercise, it is difficult to know what is going on until you "execute" the algorithm mentally. Giving a better name improve the quality of the code. Giving better names can hint you if there is a potential bug.

example:

```
// bad code
int f(int a, int b){
  return a < b ? a : b;
}

// better code
int min(int a, int b){
  return a < b ? a : b;
}

// what? there must be a bug
int max(int a, int b){
  return a < b ? a : b;
}
```

Comment: Understanding is the part I'm stuck on. Not rewriting the code.

Comment: You should be asking about the purpose of assignment !! Is it an excellent one!!